# Read a file and create arrays with the words of each column

Tags: python, arrays, file-io

I've the following file, `salida.txt` which has different number of columns in this example, just 2.

```
cil HUF, M1 NSS,
442, 1123,
20140130, 2014012,
20140131, 2014014,
```

I want to read the file and add each column into a new array. I wan't to have this:

```
['cli HUF', '442', '20140130', '20140131']
[' M1 NSS', '1123', '2014012', '2014014']
```

What I've tried so far:

```
file = open('salida.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    // add them to the arrays
```

I'm having problems to handle the number of arrays (it's not always 2, depends on the number of columns of the file) and taking each word from the line to add in the proper array. If I to put inside de loop `print line[0]` it prints me the entire line, and I want to handle it word by word.

Comment: What do you mean it's not always 2? It can be more or less?

Comment: It's the number of arrays (which depends on the columns), not the size of them, which is always the same, 4. I edited the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arrays = []
with open('salida.txt', 'r') as wordfile:
    for line in wordfile:
        # Split the line on commas.
        words = line.split(',')
        for count, word in enumerate(words):
            # Remove any whitespace.
            word = word.strip()
            # That might leave a blank string, e.g. at the end.
            if word:
                # Do we need to add another array to our list of arrays?
                if count == len(arrays):
                    arrays.append([])
                arrays[count].append(word)
print arrays
```

Answer (score 1):

Strip the last commas, and then split the line in the center commas:

```
list1, list2 = [], []
file = open('salida.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    w1, w2 = line.strip(',').split(', ')
    list1.append(w1)
    list2.append(w2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but here you create 2 arrays as the example, but as I said on the text, the number of arrays is variable which depends on the number of rows.

Comment: Ah i see.. And are there different number of columns?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the number of columns that are on the `salida.txt` file. If there are 6 columns, there would be 6 arrays, etc. Those 2 are just an example to show my problem.

Comment: No, i mean, does the number of column varies in the `salida.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
file = open('salida.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
arrays = []
words = lines[0].split(",")
for i in range(0,len(words)):
    arrays.append([words[i]])
for i in range(1,len(lines)):
    words = lines[i].split(",")
    for j in range(0,len(words)):
        arrays[j].append(words[j])
```

Comment: Thanks, but here you create 2 arrays as the example, but as I said on the text, the number of arrays is variable which depends on the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('salida.txt') as f:
    whatYouWant = zip(*list(csv.reader(f)))[:-1]
```